# I get the message: Cannot convert 'float' to 'float*' in assignment and i have some logical mistakes

Tags: c, dev-c++

I have a problem with the compiler and I must have some logical mistakes (C language)
I want to have one void function that gives me the maximum price, the minimum price and the average of a table with maximum 100 prices. And if the user gives `price=-1` I want the program to end!

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function(float pin[],int j,float *min,float *max,float *mo,int cnt);

int main()
{

    int i=0,count=0;

    float prc[100],mo;
    for(i=0;i<=99;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter price:");
        scanf("%f",&prc[i]);
            if(prc[i]==-1)
        {
            break;
        }
        count++;
    }

    int min=prc[0];
    int max=prc[0];
    void function(float prc,int i,float *min,float *max,float *mo,int count);
    printf("Minimum price is:%f Maximum price is:%f and Mo is:%f",min,max,mo);

    return 0;
}

void function(float pin[],int j,float *min,float *max,float *mo,int cnt)
{
    float sum;

    for(j=0;j<=cnt;j++)
    {
        if(pin[j]<*min)
        {
            min=pin[j];
        }
        if(pin[j]>*max)
        {
            *max=pin[j];
        }
        sum=+pin[j];
    }
    *mo=sum/j;
}
```

Comment: What is it doing/not doing in regards to what you expect?

Comment: Why do you define `int min` and `int max` when you are dealing elsewhere with `float` values?

Comment: You declare function twice, but you never call it. The declaration in main() should be a call with the actual arguments and without the return type specification. Copy & paste error?

Comment: The second declaration appears to be an attempt to call it, but you must also change `int min, max` to `float min, max`, and call the function with `... &min, &max, ...` arguments.

Comment: Change `float sum;` to `float sum = 0;` and change `sum=+pin[j];` to `sum+=pin[j];`

Comment: Please improve the title. As written, the title provides no information about the problem, which means that others with the same problem will not be able to find it. The title "I am trying to make this code work" applies to pretty much every question on this site. (You also forgot to ask a question.)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have lots of little mistakes (missing dereference, using a variable out of scope, wrong operator, etc.):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function(float pin[], float *min, float *max, float *mo, int cnt);

int main()
{
    int i=0, count=0;

    float prc[100], mo;
    for (i=0; i<=99; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter price:");
        scanf("%f", &prc[i]);
        if (prc[i] == -1)
        {
            break;
        }

        count++;
    }

    float min=prc[0];
    float max=prc[0];
    function(&prc[0], &min, &max, &mo, count);
    printf("Minimum price is:%f Maximum price is:%f and Mo is:%f", min, max, mo);

    return 0;
}

void function(float pin[], float *min, float *max, float *mo, int cnt)
{
    float sum = 0.0f;

    for (int j=0; j < cnt; j++)
    {
        if (pin[j] < *min)
        {
            *min = pin[j];
        }
        if (pin[j] > *max)
        {
            *max = pin[j];
        }

        sum += pin[j];
    }

    *mo = sum / cnt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes in the function :

I have modified the code and looks to be fine except the function argument mo , decide whether to declare it as a float pointer or a float

1. Look at the declaration inside main, u are calling a function but the syntax is for declaration.
2. used mo as argument but mo is defined as float variable whereas the function accepts a pointer as per the declaration and there are a few warning related to the types
3. Declared ints but printing them using format specifiers for float %f

## include

```
void function(float pin[],int j,float *min,float *max,float *mo,int cnt);

int main()
{

    int i=0,count=0;

    float prc[100],mo;
    for(i=0;i<=99;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter price:");
        scanf("%f",&prc[i]);
            if(prc[i]==-1)
        {
            break;
        }
        count++;
    }

    int min=prc[0];
    int max=prc[0];
    function(prc,i,min,max,mo,count);
    printf("Minimum price is:%f Maximum price is:%f and Mo is:%f",min,max,mo);

    return 0;
}

void function(float pin[],int j,float *min,float *max,float *mo,int cnt)
{
    float sum;

    for(j=0;j<=cnt;j++)
    {
        if(pin[j]<*min)
        {
            *min=pin[j];
        }
        if(pin[j]>*max)
        {
            *max=pin[j];
        }
        sum=+pin[j];
    }
    *mo=sum/j;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the analysis!

Answer (score 0):

wrong use of pointer and type,use

```
float min=prc[0];
float max=prc[0];
function(prc,i,&min,&max,&mo,count);
```

You declare as:

```
void function(float pin[],int j,float *min,float *max,float *mo,int cnt);
```

So you must deliver a float-pointer but not a float number.